# Redirect with props - React Router - Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect to a specific component (named `SingleBook`) and send along some props (`bookId`). I am using: `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"`

Following the guide https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect, I should write something like:

```
return <Redirect
    to={{
        pathname: "/book",
        state: { "bookId": "bookId" }
    }}
  />
```

And in my routes:

```
<Route path="/book" render={(props) => <SingleBook {...props}/>}/>
```

Then, on my redirected-to component I should be able to grab the props by doing somethign like:

```
const bookId = this.props.location.state.bookId
```

**HOWEVER**

It DOES redirect correctly to the `<SingleBook>` but I get the error:
`Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

I tried also to define my routes as:

```
<Route path="/book" component={SingleBook}/>
```

but I get the same error

**SingleBook component**

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react"
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

function SingleBook({props}) { // I tried also without {props}

    const bookId = this.props.location.state.bookId


    console.log(bookId)

    return(
        <Grid>
            single book {bookId}
        </Grid>
    )
}
export default SingleBook
```

Comment: Can you also show us the SingleBook component?

Comment: I edited the question including the component

Comment: @FBSO, Can you try,  ```const SingleBook = ({props}) => { ... }``` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using functional components you don't have access to `this`, you get props as argument to the functional component. So this code will work:

```
function SingleBook(props) { // Access props here without the {}

    const bookId = props.location.state.bookId; // No `this`


    console.log(bookId)

    return(
        <Grid>
            single book {bookId}
        </Grid>
    )
}
export default SingleBook
```

Comment: Why `state: { "bookId": "bookId" }` and `props.location.state.bookId` instead of `props: { "bookId": "bookId" }` and `props.location.props.bookId`? Both work, but does one make more sense?

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from "react"
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const SingleBook = () => {
    let {location: {state : {bookId} = {}} = {}} = this.props;
    let bookId = bookId;
    console.log(bookId)

    return(
        <Grid>
            single book {bookId}
        </Grid>
    )
}
export default SingleBook
```